# Mongodb query to Count days between two dates of each document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**Sample Docs :**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e7331614dd99d1a30143a58"),
    "status" : "rejected",
    "from" : ISODate("2020-03-17T08:46:02.552Z"),
    "to" : ISODate("2020-03-18T08:46:07.124Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e7331614dd99d1a30143a58"),
    "status" : "rejected",
    "from" : ISODate("2020-03-02T08:08:32.819Z"),
    "to" : ISODate("2020-03-05T08:08:37.125Z"),
}
```

I am new to mongodb, I want to count the number of days between dates (to and from fields) of each document where status is equal to 'rejected'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** Filter out docs */
  { $match: { status: "rejected" } },
  /** subtract two dates gets timestamp & divide to convert to days & round value */
  {
    $addFields: {
      daysCount: {
        $round: { $divide: [{ $subtract: ["$to", "$from"] }, 86400000] }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4AKIVims3Gi)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MongoDB version 5.0, you can use the new $dateDiff operator for this.
Docs Link:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateDiff/#mongodb-expression-exp.-dateDiff

Answer (score 0):

Subtract dates using [$subtract](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) operator ans then convert (use [$divide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/)) result in milliseconds to days:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
      {
        "$project": {            
          "date_diff": { "$subtract": ["$to", "$from"] }
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {             
          "days": { "$divide": ["$date_diff", 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24] }
        }
      }
    ])
```

Here there's two [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) phases in pipeline just for easy visualization, but it could to be merged at one pipeline phase.

Additionally you may want to convert the number of days from float to integers. It's up to you!